# Problem when downloading multiple pdfs using download.file

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am currently trying to download around 1,200 pdfs from this [online repository](https://www.ssoar.info/ssoar/discover?scope=/&sort_by=score&order=desc&rpp=100&filtertype_0=dateIssued&filter_relational_operator_0=equals&filter_0=%5B2000+TO+2022%5D&filtertype=journal&filter_relational_operator=equals&filter=Historical+Social+Research)(the link has my built-in filtering parameters) and I am struggling to to get the pdfs to download. I currently have this code, which either fails to download any pdfs or only downloads one article at a time and overrides the previous one:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

url <- "https://www.ssoar.info/ssoar/discover?scope=/&sort_by=score&order=desc&rpp=100&filtertype_0=dateIssued&filter_relational_operator_0=equals&filter_0=%5B2000+TO+2022%5D&filtertype=journal&filter_relational_operator=equals&filter=Historical+Social+Research"
page <- read_html(url)

urls_pdf <- page %>% 
  html_elements("a") %>% 
  html_attr("href") %>% 
  str_subset("\\.pdf") 

urls_pdf[1:100] %>% walk2(basename(.), download.file, mode = "wb")

dir(pattern = "\\.pdf")
```

When running the code, I expected the desired pdfs to all be downloaded into the folder I preselected, but I keep getting the error "There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)", which upon further examining shows this:

Warning messages:

1: In .f(.x[[i]], .y[[i]], ...) :
URL https://www.ssoar.info/ssoar/bitstream/handle/document/6292/ssoar-hsr-2007-no_4__no_122-ambrosius_et_al-alte_pfade_der_integration_und.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y&lnkname=ssoar-hsr-2007-no_4__no_122-ambrosius_et_al-alte_pfade_der_integration_und.pdf: cannot open destfile 'ssoar-hsr-2007-no_4__no_122-ambrosius_et_al-alte_pfade_der_integration_und.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y&lnkname=ssoar-hsr-2007-no_4__no_122-ambrosius_et_al-alte_pfade_der_integration_und.pdf', reason 'Invalid argument'

2: In .f(.x[[i]], .y[[i]], ...) : download had nonzero exit status

...

I will be honest and say I am not the most experienced with r, but I am a bit unsure how I should proceed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
lapply(X = urls_pdf,
       FUN = \(x) utils::download.file(url = x, 
                                       destfile = basename(path = x), 
                                       quiet = TRUE)
       )
```

`lapply(X, FUN)` works like a for-loop. `\(x)` is shorthand for `function(x)`. `download.file()` is exported from `{utils}`.

To store in a pre-selected folder do

```
path <- "path_to_your_prespecified_folder"

lapply(X = urls_pdf,
       FUN = \(x) utils::download.file(url = x, 
                                       destfile = file.path(path, basename(x)), 
                                       quiet = TRUE)
       )
```

The argument (parameter) `quiet = TRUE` is not necessary. If I am asked to download multiple files, I prefer the job to be down silently.

Notice, I see no reason for the use of `{tidyverse}`. You could rewrite your code to collect the pdf urls by replacing the pipe operator with `|>` which is `base R`:

```
library(rvest)

url <- "https://www.ssoar.info/ssoar/discover?scope=/&sort_by=score&order=desc&rpp=100&filtertype_0=dateIssued&filter_relational_operator_0=equals&filter_0=%5B2000+TO+2022%5D&filtertype=journal&filter_relational_operator=equals&filter=Historical+Social+Research"
page <- read_html(url)

urls_pdf <- page |>
  html_elements("a") |>
  html_attr("href") |>
  str_subset("\\.pdf")
```

This allows you to write one piped code block like this:

```
path <- "/Users/blablabla/Desktop/pdfs" # adjust accordingly!

page |>
  html_elements("a") |>
  html_attr("href") |>
  str_subset("\\.pdf") |>
  lapply(X = _,
         FUN = \(x) 
         download.file(url = x, 
                       destfile = file.path(path, basename(x)), 
                       quiet = TRUE)
  )
```

Note. When using `|>`, `_` is used as placeholder for the data. `_` for `|>` is like `.` for `%>%`.

Your code currently collects 100 pdfs. What about the remaining ~1,100 pdfs?

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment, the code worked exactly as planned. To your final question, I wanted to get the first page of code working before I added the loop to grab the other pages (it was a test run that would take less processing time; I'm not operating with an advanced laptop, which means the full code will take more time than I wanted to commit to the dry run).